# Reassigning variables c++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I am trying to reassign the public variable overallRating to the value 7. It is initially set equal to 0 in the constructor. My code compiles, but when I try to access the schoolName.overallRating in another file it says that overallRating = 0 instead of 7. Is there something wrong with my assignment statement? The GradSchool class just contains a list of schools.

School.cc

```
#include "school.h"

School::School()
 {
   women = 0;
   rateAI = 0;
   rateSys = 0;
   rateTheory = 0;
   effectiveness = 0;
   ratePubs = 0;
   overallRating = 0;
 }

School::School (string myName, string myState, int theWomen, int myRateAI, int myRateSys,int myRateTheory, int myEffectiveness, int myRatePubs)
 {
   name = myName;
   state = myState;
   women = theWomen;
   rateAI = myRateAI;
   rateSys = myRateSys;
   rateTheory = myRateTheory;
   effectiveness = myEffectiveness;
   ratePubs = myRatePubs;
   overallRating = 0;
 }

void School::computeRating (int weightWomen, int weightAI, int weightSys, int weightTheory, int weightEffect, int weightPubs)
{
  overallRating = 7;
}

void School::printSchoolInfo ()
{
  cout<<"Name: "<<name<<endl;
  cout<<"State: "<<state<<endl;
  cout<<"Rating of number of women PhD's: "<<women<<endl; 
  cout<<"Rating of AI program: "<<rateAI<<endl;
  cout<<"Rating of Systems program: "<<rateSys<<endl;
  cout<<"Rating of Theory program: "<<rateTheory<<endl;
  cout<<"Effctiveness rating: "<<effectiveness<<endl;
  cout<<"Rating of faculty publications: "<<ratePubs<<endl;
  cout<<"Overall rating: "<<overallRating<<endl;
}
```

School.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef SCHOOL_H
#define SCHOOL_H
class School {
  public:
    string name;      // name of the school
    string state;     // state in which school is located
    int women;      // rating of percentage of women PhD's (1 to 10)
    int rateAI;     // rating of AI program (1 to 10)
    int rateSys;      // rating of Computer Systems program (1 to 10)
    int rateTheory;   // rating of Theory program (1 to 10)
    int effectiveness;  // rating of effectiveness in educating research scholars 
    int ratePubs;     // rating of impact of publications per faculty member 
    int overallRating;  // overall rating that considers all of the above factors 

    School ();
    School (string myName, string myState, int theWomen, int myRateAI, int myRateSys,
        int myRateTheory, int myEffectiveness, int myRatePubs);
    void printSchoolInfo ();
    void computeRating (int weightWomen, int weightAI, int weightSys, 
                int weightTheory, int weightEffect, int weightPubs);
};    
#endif
```

main

```
 //
// gradSchoolTest.cc
//
// code to test the creation of a GradSchools object that stores and sorts
// multiple instances of a School
#include <iostream>
#include "gradSchools.h"
#include "gradSchools.cc"
#include "school.h"
#include "school.cc"
#include "sortable_list.h"
#include "sortable_list.cc"
#include "list.h"
#include "list.cc"
using namespace std;

GradSchools makeGradSchools () {
    // Note that the ratings here are somewhat arbitrary
    GradSchools newSchools;
    newSchools.addSchool("MIT", "Massachusetts", 5, 10, 9, 10, 10, 7);
    newSchools.addSchool("Stanford", "California", 9, 8, 5, 8, 10, 9);
    newSchools.addSchool("CMU", "Pennsylvania", 6, 9, 9, 7, 8, 6);
    newSchools.addSchool("UC Berkeley", "California", 4, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9);
    newSchools.addSchool("Cornell", "New York", 9, 5, 8, 9, 9, 8);
    newSchools.addSchool("Univ. of Illinois", "Illinois", 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7);
    newSchools.addSchool("Univ. of Washington", "Washington", 7, 5, 7, 8, 8, 8);
    newSchools.addSchool("Princeton", "New Jersey", 8, 4, 5, 8, 7, 10);
    return newSchools;
} //makeGradSchools

int main (void) {
    GradSchools myGradSchools = makeGradSchools();
    int weightWomen = 5;
    int weightAI = 5; 
    int weightSys = 2;
    int weightTheory = 0;
    int weightEffectiveness = 5;
    int weightPubs = 4;
    myGradSchools.rankSchools(weightWomen, weightAI, weightSys, weightTheory, weightEffectiveness, weightPubs);
    cout << endl;
    myGradSchools.rankSchoolsFactor("AI");
    myGradSchools.rankSchoolsFactor("women");
    myGradSchools.printGradSchools();

    return 0;
} //end main
```

GradSchools

```
#include "gradSchools.h"

/*Implement functions from gradSchools.h file here */
GradSchools::GradSchools()
 {
   schools.clear();
 }
void GradSchools::addSchool (string name, string state, int women, int rateAI, int rateSys,int rateTheory, int effect, int ratePubs)
 {   
schools.insert(schools.size(), (School(name, state, women, rateAI, rateSys, rateTheory, effect, ratePubs)));
 }

void GradSchools::computeRatings (int weightWomen, int weightAI, int weightSys, int weightTheory, int weightEffect, int weightPubs)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < schools.size()-1; i++)
     {
       School entry;
       schools.retrieve(i, entry);
       entry.computeRating(weightWomen, weightAI, weightSys, weightTheory, weightEffect, weightPubs);
     }
 }
void GradSchools::rankSchools (int weightWomen, int weightAI, int weightSys, int weightTheory, int weightEffect, int weightPubs)
 {
   computeRatings(weightWomen, weightAI, weightSys, weightTheory, weightEffect, weightPubs);
   schools.selection_sort();
   for (int i = schools.size()-1; i>= 0; i--)
     {
       School x;
       schools.retrieve(i, x);
       cout<<x.name<<endl;
     }

 }
void GradSchools::rankSchoolsFactor (string factor)
 {

 } 

void GradSchools::printGradSchools()
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < schools.size()-1; i++)
     {
       School entry;
       schools.retrieve(i, entry);
       entry.printSchoolInfo();
       cout<<endl;
     }
 }
```

retrieve

```
template<class List_entry>
Error_code List<List_entry> :: retrieve(int position, List_entry &x ) const
  /*Post: If 0¾ position < n, where n is the number of entries in the List,
  the function succeeds: The entry at position is copied to x; all
  List entries remain unchanged.
  Else: The function fails with a diagnostic error code.*/
{
  if (position < 0 || position >= count) {
    return range_error;
  }
  x = entry[position];
  return success;
} //retrieve
```

Comment: Invert in your main printSchoolInfo and computeRating.

Comment: Might be silly but, do you call `computeRating` before checking if the value of overallRating has changed?

Comment: What do you mean by checking if it has changed? I call computeRating() before I call printSchoolInfo().

Comment: @Steve But you don't show that anywhere. Please post an MCVE, as suggested in the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    School entry;
>    schools.retrieve(i, entry);
>    entry.computeRating(weightWomen, weightAI, weightSys, weightTheory, weightEffect, weightPubs);
> ```

Although not visible in your code, I imagine that `schools` is some collection and that the function `retrieve` retrieves some element in the array.

The problem is that your code above works on a *copy* of the entry, not the entry itself. Therefore, the element in the `schools` collection is not modified, because `computeRating` is invoked on the **copied** `entry` variable, not the element itself.

To fix completely your code, we need to see how `retrieve` works, and modify it in a way so that we can get a *reference* to the element, not a *copy*.

A suggestion: modify your `retrieve` function so that it returns a *reference* to the element. In other words, make it have the following signature:

```
School& retrieve(int i);
```

and later, modify the quoted code this way:

```
    School& entry = schools.retrieve(i);
    entry.computeRating(weightWomen, weightAI, weightSys, weightTheory, weightEffect, weightPubs);
```

**EDIT** after seeing your retrieve function, if it really needs the result to be an *out parameter*, you can still

```
Error_code List<List_entry> :: retrieve(int position, List_entry*& x ) const // set the output param as a pointer
{
  if (position < 0 || position >= count) {
    return range_error;
  }
  x = &entry[position]; // return a pointer
  return success;
}
```

and later, the quoted code becomes:

```
    School* entry;
    schools.retrieve(i, entry);
    entry->computeRating(weightWomen, weightAI, weightSys, weightTheory, weightEffect, weightPubs);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the retrieve function.

Comment: @Steve see my suggestion for modifying the `retrieve` function. In fact, you seem to return an error code instead of an element reference, and I dont see anywhere where you check this code. Why do you need it this way?

Comment: However if you insist of having it this way, you will need to use a pointer.  See my Edit for a solution that keeps the logic of your function (returning a code), although I dont think it is a recommended design pattern (think of throwing an exception when the index is out of bound, instead of returning an error-code).